# Number of primes between two integers x and y (with x < y and excluding x and y)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

There is a formula given at the bottom of the following webpage:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288747/how-to-find-number-of-prime-numbers-between-two-integers

to calculate the number of primes between two integers x and y (with x < y and excluding x and y).

The formula is:

```
PrimePi[y - 1] - PrimePi[x + 1]
```

(where I'm using Mathematica's prime counting function `PrimePi` instead of `Pi[n]`).

I'm attempting to build and improve the above formula.

The following examples suggest a way to get such a formula:

---

(** Example 1: Find the primes between 10 and 20:  **)

```
table1 = Table[Prime[i], {i, PrimePi[NextPrime[10]], PrimePi[NextPrime[20, -1]]}]
(* {11, 13, 17, 19} *)

Length[table1]
(* 4 *)
```

---

(** Example 2: Find the primes between 10 and 50:  **)

```
table2 = Table[Prime[i], {i, PrimePi[NextPrime[10]], PrimePi[NextPrime[50, -1]]}]
(* {11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47} *)

Length[table2]
(* 11 *)
```

---

(** Example 3: Find the primes between 11 and 47 (excluding 11 and 47):  **)

```
table3 = Table[Prime[i], {i, PrimePi[NextPrime[11]], PrimePi[NextPrime[47, -1]]}]
(* {13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43} *)

Length[table3]
(* 9 *)
```

---

But when I attempt to build the function:

```
NumberOfPrimes[L_, M_] = Length[Table[Prime[i], {i, PrimePi[NextPrime[L]], PrimePi[NextPrime[M, -1]]}]]
```

I get a message:

> "Table::iterb: Iterator {i,PrimePi[NextPrime[L]],PrimePi[NextPrime[M,-1]]} does not have appropriate bounds."

As far as I know; a function to calculate the number of primes between two integers does not exist in Mathematica's repertoire a priori. Can anyone help me to build this function?  Thank you!

Comment: Lookup `:=` vs `=`.

Comment: Please use proper formatting of *Mathematica* code: indent the code block 4 spaces. That way it's easy for users to copy the code into a notebook.

Comment: Also, why did you insert all those spaces into the URL you cite so that it's no longer a hyperlink. If you avoid inserting the spurious spaces, you'll directly get a hyperlink: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288747/how-to-find-number-of-prime-numbers-between-two-integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Kuba said, use `:=` and not `=`, that is:

```
    numberOfPrimes[a_, b_] := 
       Length@Table[Prime[i], {i, PrimePi@NextPrime[a], PrimePi@NextPrime[b, -1]}]
    numberOfPrimes[11, 47]
(* 9 *)
```

The reason you cannot use `=` (abbreviation for `Set`), which tries to evaluate the right-hand side and *immediately* assign it to the left-hand side, is that you don't have any specific values for the symbols used in the iterator bounds.

**Style suggestions:**

- Please do *not* use uppercase letters `L` and `M` for your function arguments. Names beginning with uppercase letters should be reserved for *Mathematica*'s built-in objects. And since lowercase `l` is hard to distinguish from the number `1`, it would be better to use different letters entirely, such as my `a` and `b`.
- Likewise, don't use an uppercase letter to begin your name for the function (unless you're designing a package).
- The "trick" of using prefix notation `@` in the definition of the functions obviates the need for so many nested square brackets.

**Why not just use `PrimePi`?**

Is there some particular reason you want to define this function instead of using literally the mathematical formula you found (changing $\pi$ to `PrimePi` of course)? Using `PrimePi` seems to be more efficient:

```
   Table[
        {a, b} = Sort@RandomInteger[{500, 1000}, 2];
        First /@ Timing /@ {numberOfPrimes[a, b], PrimePi[b] - PrimePi[a]},
      {10}] // TableForm
(*
  5.*10^-6  1.*10^-6
  2.*10^-6  1.*10^-6
  1.*10^-6  1.*10^-6
  1.*10^-6  0.
  2.*10^-6  0.
  1.*10^-6  0.
  2.*10^-6  1.*10^-6
  2.*10^-6  0.
  0.        0.
  1.*10^-6, 0.
*)
```

Comment: @Kuba Indeed := works! Thank you Kuba!

Comment: Thank you for your alternative approach! Have a great weekend!

Comment: @ Murray: My last entry was addressed to you. Thanks!